# Averaging values in array corresponding to the values of another array

Tags: python, numpy, average

I have an array that contains numbers that are distances, and another that represents certain values at that distance. How do I calculate the average of all the data at a fixed value of the distance?

e.g distances (d): `[1 1 14 6 1 12 14 6 6 7 4 3 7 9 1 3 3 6 5 8]`

e.g data corresponding to the entry of the distances:

therefore value=3.3 at d=1; value=2,1 at d=1; value=3.5 at d=14; etc..

`[3.3 2.1 3.5 2.5 4.6 7.4 2.6 7.8 9.2 10.11 14.3 2.5 6.7 3.4 7.5 8.5 9.7 4.3 2.8 4.1]`

For example, at distance d=6 I should do the mean of 2.5, 7.8, 9.2 and 4.3

I've used the following code that works, but I do not know how to store the values into a new array:

```
from numpy import mean

for d in set(key): 
    print d, mean([dist[i] for i in range(len(key)) if key[i] == d])
```

Please help! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You've got the hard part done, just putting your results into a new list is as easy as:

```
result = []
for d in set(key): 
    result.append(mean([dist[i] for i in range(len(key)) if key[i] == d]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `pandas`

```
g = pd.DataFrame({'d':d, 'k':k}).groupby('d')
```

Option 1: `transform` to get the values in the same positions

```
g.transform('mean').values
```

Option2: `mean` directly and get a `dict` with the mapping

```
g.mean().to_dict()['k']
```

Answer (score 0):

***Setup***

```
d = np.array(
  [1, 1, 14, 6, 1, 12, 14, 6, 6, 7, 4, 3, 7, 9, 1, 3, 3, 6, 5, 8]
)

k = np.array(
  [3.3,2.1,3.5,2.5,4.6,7.4,2.6,7.8,9.2,10.11,14.3,2.5,6.7,3.4,7.5,8.5,9.7,4.3,2.8,4.1]
)
```

---

#### `scipy.sparse` + `csr_matrix`

```
from scipy import sparse

s = d.shape[0]
r = np.arange(s+1)
m = d.max() + 1
b = np.bincount(d)

out = sparse.csr_matrix( (k, d, r), (s, m) ).sum(0).A1

(out / b)[d]
```

```
array([ 4.375,  4.375,  3.05 ,  5.95 ,  4.375,  7.4  ,  3.05 ,  5.95 ,
        5.95 ,  8.405, 14.3  ,  6.9  ,  8.405,  3.4  ,  4.375,  6.9  ,
        6.9  ,  5.95 ,  2.8  ,  4.1  ])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `array` from the `numpy` lib in combination with `where`, also from the same lib.

You can define a function to get the positions of the desired distances:

```
from numpy import mean, array, where  

def key_distances(distances, d):
  return where(distances == d)[0]
```

then you use it for getting the values at those positions.

Let's say you have:

```
d = array([1,1,14,6,1,12,14,6,6,7,4,3,7,9,1,3,3,6,5,8])
v = array([3.3,2.1,3.5,2.5,4.6,7.4,2.6,7.8,9.2,10.11,14.3,2.5,6.7,3.4,7.5,8.5,9.7,4.3,2.8,4.1])
```

Then you might do something like:

```
vs = v[key_distances(d,d[1])]
```

Then get your mean:

```
print mean(vs)
```

Answer (score 0):

The [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package (disclaimer: I am its author) was designed with these use-cases in mind:

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
npi.group_by(d).mean(dist)
```

Pandas can do similar things; but its api isnt really tailored to these things; and for such an elementary operation as a group-by I feel its kinda wrong to have to hoist your data into a completely new datastructure.